# What's the default URL parameter of Akamai's HTTP proxy?

Tags: proxy, default, akamai

I was trying to start a local server at work, and Spring boot failed to do so because port `9085` was already busy. So I `netstat -a` the computer, and saw a `TCP 10.57.112.116:9085 a92-122-122-161:http ESTABLISHED` line. I guessed that is represented an IP adress, and so I went to `http://92.122.122.161/` on a browser (Firefox).

Then, the website yelled

```
Invalid URL
The requested URL "[no URL]", is invalid.

Reference #9.9d7a7a5c.1491988322.9d7d4ab
```

I dig a bit, and I tried `http://92.122.122.161/redirect` which yelled

```
The requested URL "http://%5bNo%20Host%5d/redirect", is invalid.
```

So it seems that I could ask for a precise resource, if I know how to pass the host and protocol.

Looking on Duckduckgo, I saw that this looks like an Akamai's proxy.

**How can I ask that Akamai proxy to show me a precise resource, like `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=akamai` ?**

I tried `http://92.122.122.161/duckduckgo.com` and few variants, but it returns a `[No URL]`. Maybe there's some custom company-set parameters, but what's the default way to ask for a specific URL to this Akamai proxy?

Answer (score 0):

you mean you want to test the URL from the staging akamai edge server? If yes then you can spoof the IP returned by nslookup www.example.com.edgekey-staging.net